# Why won't my form inputs push into the array?

Tags: javascript, html

All my variables are rightly placed, however, the code still doesn't run.
So no matter how I tinkered with the code, the data in the form doesn't register the information. Can someone tell me what exactly is the error in this code?

```
<div class="regi-04">
            <label for="phone"></label>
            <div>
                <input id="phone" name="form05" type="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Your Phone">
            </div><br>
        </div>
<div class="submit">
        <button class="button02" onclick=" regisUser(); "> 
        Proceed With Registration </button></div> 
<script>
var registers = [
{name1: "user", username: "user345" , email: "abc123@gmail.com", phone: "09999" , country: "Germany", password: "password123"}
];
  
function regisUser() {
      
  var nam = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var mail = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var pho = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  var kuni = document.getElementById("country").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("password").value
      
registers.push({name1:nam, username:user, email:mail, phone:pho, country:kuni, password:pass})
alert(registers.length)
  } </script>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't run".  Currently the code shown would produce an error, visible in the browser's development console.  Is that what you're talking about?  What does the error tell you?  If that's not what you're talking about, can you expand this code into a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what isn't working as you expect?

Comment: The `onclick` in your code seems to activate 3 functions and only one is shown, so can you show the other two? Or maybe those two functions don't exist?

Comment: I've removed the other two functions so that the error may not occur, but it still doesn't push the information sadly

Comment: I see... so far I can't find out why it doesn't push the information, though! The alert message still appears with the text `1`, doesn't it?

Comment: `document.getElementById("name")` is null, so `var nam = document.getElementById("name").value;` will break your script

Answer (score 0):

function Validate is not defined, run the snippet here or in the browser dev tools console.

```js
var registers = [
{name1: "user", username: "user345" , email: "abc123@gmail.com", phone: "09999" , country: "Germany", password: "password123"}
];
  
function regisUser() {
      
  var nam = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var mail = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var pho = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  var kuni = document.getElementById("country").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("password").value
      
registers.push({name1:nam, username:user, email:mail, phone:pho, country:kuni, password:pass})
alert(registers.length)
  }
```

```html
<div class="submit">
        <button class="button02" onclick="validate(); regisUser(); checkNum();"> 
        Proceed With Registration </button></div>
```